# there exists in NestJs some similar to express-async-errors to save us from writing try catch in each asynchronous function?

Tags: nestjs

In the past when I did my applications only in express, I used the [express-async-errors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-errors) module to save myself from writing catch-try blocks.

**Is there a similar way in NestJs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use exception filter https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters